# RMariaDB failing with Bad Handshake

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database with RMariaDB but getting bad handshake errors both on MacOS and Fedora.

```
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), 
    user = 'user', host = 'host', password = 'password',
    client.flag = RMariaDB::CLIENT_SSL)
```

It works fine on the command line. SSL is required. Am I calling the wrong flag with RMariaDB::CLIENT_SSL?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Does the error message contain an alert code? If not try to capture with wireshark and check the handshake packets (Filter ssl)

Comment: Exact error is: "Error in connection_create(host, username, password, dbname, as.integer(port),  : 
  Failed to connect: Bad handshake"

If I don't pass the client.flag I get the error: "Error in connection_create(host, username, password, dbname, as.integer(port),  : 
  Failed to connect: Access denied for user 'myUser'@'myIPAddress' (using password: YES)"

I'll try to capture the alert code when in the office tomorrow. Thanks for taking a look.